# how to declare an array using a variable while receiving value of variable as input? Check my Code

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, c++14

```
int a;
cin>>a;
int arr[a];
```

I want to declare an array according to size of the user. I am new to programming .
What can be done? Is this method correct?

Comment: ***Is this method correct?*** No `std::vector` is the `c++` way to create a dynamic array. VLAs are not legal in the language. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Answer (score 2):

The thing you want to achieve is called Variable Length Array, in short VLA [which isn't a part of C++ standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard).

> What can be done?

It invokes an [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

> Is this method correct?

Nope. The best opportunity of taking a little help of [`std::vector<>`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) worth here. It dynamically allocates the requested bytes of data and optionally, you can initialize them with their required values.

You can achieve this like:

```
int n = 0;
std::cin >> n; // make sure it's a valid size
std::vector<int> a(n);
```

---

In case you wants it to keep growing runtime, just use its `push_back()` method and you can get the vector size through its `size()`.

Comment: The OP can also use the `std::vector::push_back()` method and let the vector grow during runtime.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews yup, I intentionally put that example because it's similar to what OP actually wants. Appreciate you reminded me of that though!

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged this C++, in which case there are very few excuses not to solve this with a std::vector.

If you *must* do it C style you can write:

```
int a;
cin >> a;
int * arr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * a);
```

or better (as per Thomas' comment below):

```
int a;
cin >> a;
int * arr = new int[a];
```

but a vector is definitely preferred.

Comment: Prefer to use operator `new` instead of `malloc`.  The `malloc` function does not call constructors.  Also, the `new` operator does not require casting.

Comment: Agreed completely. I reverted to old school C completely and probably shouldn't have.